# save data into flash media server like rdbms

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server, shared-objects

hii... 
im using fms to save datas like rdbms. Im using shared object for this. But I cant save more than one row of data into flash media server. What can I do for this purpose??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you save an array of "rows" into the shared object instead of just one row?